# Angular UI Router Regex for non-stateParams segements

Tags: regex, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

I have 2 URL patterns that I want to target the same state:

- `/:client/:project/deliverables/resources_reports/:id/resources/:rsrc_id`
- `/:client/:project/deliverables/issues_exports/:id/resources/:rsrc_id`

I tried making a single state to manage this using regex to no avail. I'm not sure if the regexp is only applicable to the $stateParam keys in those URLs or not.  Is there a way to make it something like this:

```
url: "/:client/:project/deliverables/(resources_reports|issues_exports)/:id/resources/:rsrc_id"`
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing one thing: it has to be set within a Url matcher's matching segment.  The unexpected result is that you get another $stateParams property to utilize.

```
/:client/:project/deliverables/{d_type:resources_reports|issues_exports}/:id/resources/:rsrc_id
```